# How do i add contrast to a text on a html website?

Tags: html, css

I'm coding a website with html and css and I wanna make the backround black but one of my text on the site is black too. I wanna leave it on black I just wanna cover the letters's edges with white so its still visible. How do i do it? I tried some things but still not clear how to do it.

Comment: In order to help you, show us what you tried

Comment: it's a basic question which has nothing to do about trying. There isnt much to code at all. You simply need to know that you can use `text-shadow` to create a border. Which espcecially beginners wouldnt as it is a rarely used method.

Answer (score 2):

simply use a text-shadow to create a "border".

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

p {
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`text-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) is the CSS property your looking for.

- You can combine multiple flat text-shadow to make a flat border around your letters
- You can use the blur option to have a softer way of enhancing

```css
p {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background: black;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
}

p.no-blur{
  text-shadow: 1px 1px white, -1px 1px white, 1px -1px white, -1px -1px white;
}

p.blur{
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px white;
}
```

```html
<p class='no-blur'>I'm a black text on black</p>
<p class='blur'>I'm a black text on black</p>
```